# java-how to return multiple values in an array in switch case

Tags: java

I want to return all the array elements which satisfies the if statement in the code above.

Here the output is all the first element which satisfies the if condition.

```
switch(ch) {
     case 1: {
        g = prob1 * totoutcome;
        flag = (int) g;
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
             if(a1[0][0].equals(veh[i]) && flag > 0) {  
              flag--;
              return(id[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + number[i] + " " + veh[i] + " " + color[i] + " " + type[i] + "\n");
             }
     }
     break;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do? What is the mean of each variable?

Comment: return statement can return just a single "item". Be it a list of values, an integer, a string or anything of that sort. This is pretty basic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` means go back to the function that called you (and not go back and come back to return another) carrying the variable returned.

To achieve what you want.. you can create a list, add the elements to return to the list and return the list after ending your for loop.

Comment: upvote for understand the question =) I tried but now I see what he ask

Answer (score 0):

```
     ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ab = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ac = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ad = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ae = new ArrayList<String>();
for(.....)
{
if()
{
                             aa.add(name[i]);
                             ab.add(number[i]);
                             ac.add(veh[i]);
                             ad.add(color[i]);
                             ae.add(type[i]);
}

}
return(aa+ab+ac+ad+ae);
```

Comment: This response would be even better if accompanied by a few words of explanation.